# Connected Component in Undirected Graph in python

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

Find connected component in undirected graph. Each node in the graph contains a label and a list of its neighbors. this is the link: https://www.lintcode.com/problem/431/ Leetcode requires membership for this question.

```
class UndirectedGraphNode:
     def __init__(self, x):
         self.label = x
         self.neighbors = []
```

I solved it this way but it returns []

```
class Solution:
    def connectedSet(self, nodes):
        res=[]
        visited=set()
        def dfs(node,path):
            if not node:
                res.append(path.copy())
                return
            if node in visited:
                return
            visited.add(node)
            for neighbor in node.neighbors:              
                if neighbor not in visited:
                    print(path)
                    dfs(neighbor,path+[node.label])
        for node in nodes:
            if node not in visited:
                dfs(node,[])
        return res
```

This returns []. I belive its logic correct. Run depth first search checking if the node is not visited, till no node exists.

**Input Data**

```
 {1,2,4#2,1,4#3,5#4,1,2#5,3}
```

**Expected Result**

```
 [[1,2,4],[3,5]]
```

**Result**

```
[]
```

Comment: "till no node exists" and the equivalent code `if not node:` is not a correct end condition; looking at the Node class, this condition will never fire.

Comment: Please show a simple example of input data, and *expected* result.

Comment: @kcsquared I figured that base case is not firing but what should be the base case. I could not figured out solution for months. I found online solution but I ahve to memorize but my brain has no space for memorizing. I keep forgetting

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve In order to make this reproducible, I have to implement a grpah class. that is why I shared the link for the code

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I did

Comment: I think there was a copy-paste error with that input data; `#` creates comments in Python, so it may have messed up your intended formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition `if not node:` doesn't make sense: you're not modifying nodes or making them Falsey. Depth first search explores a forest of rooted trees. Your outer loop over nodes looks for the roots of these trees, so you should just pass a reference to an empty list into `dfs`, to track all the nodes explored in the search tree for that root:

```py
class Solution:
    def connectedSet(self, nodes):
        res = []
        visited = set()

        def dfs(node, path):
            path.append(node.label)
            visited.add(node)
            for neighbor in node.neighbors:
                if neighbor not in visited:
                    dfs(neighbor, path)

        for node in nodes:
            if node not in visited:
                path = []
                dfs(node, path)
                res.append(sorted(path.copy()))
        return res
```

Comment: did you run the code on lintcode platform it gives me this error: "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'UndirectedGraphNode' and 'UndirectedGraphNode'
"

Comment: @Yilmaz No; I also didn't understand your provided input data for the graph. The problem is that your UndirectedGraphNode class isn't hashable by default; you probably want to use the label attributes instead.

Comment: Yeah I figured out that path. It gives me wrong answer. Values are not in correct order

Comment: I had to add this to get accepted `res.append(sorted(path.copy()))` I dont know why i have to add this

Comment: @Yilmaz Your question text doesn't mention any order... Could you give a sample input and output for your code?

Comment: Can you pls take a look at this problem when you have time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73422529/optimize-perfect-squares-problem-similar-to-coin-change-in-python